# Less file is not including in asps page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, web, less

i am converting a complete html template to aspx pages but when i include

```
 <link href="themes/less/bootstrap.less" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/less">
<script src="themes/js/less/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

these lines in my aspx page they are not including the less style files wjile in php it works correctly.!

I have read soo many posts on stake overflow.msdn articles but could not fix the error can any one give me authentic answer

Answer (score -1):

Include Css file reference like :

```
 <link href="themes/less/bootstrap.less" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can read more about it here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbze79kd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: it shows the error..in filebug view....Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost:53377/themes/less/bootstrap.less